# Dump data into single XML file from MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are looking for a way to automatically save all data from MS SQL 2008 R2 via our application GUI (not SSMS). We want to export all data from all tables into a **single XML** using 'for XML Auto' where the table name begins with 'Params'.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
@command1 = N'CAST(select * from ? for xml auto)',
@whereand = N'and o.name like ''Params%''') AS XML)
```

does the selection nicely, but the problem is that all table data will result in a separate XML stream, however, I want to create a single XML.

How would I go about combining the result sets into one? Shall I copy and modify sp_MSforeachtable or is there a way to use the standard SP? I'd like to make this selection as fast as possible so I'd like to avoid selecting XMLs into a temp table then concatenating them into a single XML stream.

Comment: Check out this blog post: [Selecting the entire Database as XML String](http://sqlity.net/en/577/selecting-the-entire-database-as-xml-string/). I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Because the application settings are to be saved via the GUI into XML so it can be copied to another system if needed, mostly copied between development, test, and production landscapes. This is something that the operator of the system must do and no, they can't and won't have direct access to the database due to obvois security reasons.

Comment: I am not sure where you see a temp table being used. My solution dynamically builds a single select and then executes that. There are no temp tables involved. The first code snippet just creates some tables with data to test the process. The second snippet is the actual solution to your question.

Comment: You're right, I deleted my comment. Thanks for the help.